# Android ScrollView not scrolling by no means

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I have a rather complex layout where I mainly show a picture with text over it (overlapped) and some buttons at the bottom. I set the text dynamically, and in some cases it exceeds TextBox heigtht, so I decided to add a ScrollView, but no matter what I try, ScrollView will never work (scroll) and the "hidden" text will never be displayed.

I have read all related StackOverflow posts with no luck, I've also tried         **android:fillViewport="true"** with no luck also and no luck with **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"** in AndroidManifest.

Any other ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/rlThought">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:cropToPadding="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/frame_border_phone" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvThought"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:shadowColor="#000"
                            android:shadowDx="2"
                            android:shadowDy="2"
                            android:shadowRadius="6"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:textColor="#FFF"
                            android:textSize="28sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/llFrameInfo"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--llSignature-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/llSignature"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSignaturePrefix"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSignature"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!--llTrackDetails-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/llTrackDetails"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/llSignature"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTrackDetailsTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTrackDetails"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!--Copyright-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/llCopyright"
                    android:layout_below="@id/llTrackDetails"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCopyright"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/animOverlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/llBottomMenu"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivShareImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_share"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/thought_share" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivShareVideo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_share"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/thought_share" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivSave"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/save"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/thought_save" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPlay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/play"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/track_play" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPause"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/pause"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/track_stop" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/animSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 1:

OK, after long time of trial and error I got ScrollView partially working. I have removed the second RelativeLayout (counting from top) and don't know why but started to work, but the problem now is that you see the text cut and not full text, even that you can scroll :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll answer my own question again in case it helps anyone else facing the same problem.
In my particular case setting the ScrollView content (TextView in my case) layout_height as "wrap_content" was causing ScrollView not to scroll (why???) while if I set a fixed value scroll starts working, so in the end, what I've done to make it to work, was to calculate ScrollView content in code and set its layout_height dynamically.

Calculating ScrollView content height dynamically was a rather complex task, as I needed to do it before views are rendered, but this is subject for another thread :), the fact is calculating content height and setting its layout_height dynamically have done the trick for me.

Happy coding to all.